# NSPredicate compare with Integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

How can I compare two NSNumbers or a NSNumber and an Integer in an NSPredicate?

I tried:

```
NSNumber *stdUserNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"standardUser"]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %@", stdUserNumber];
```

Well, this doesn't work ... anyone has an idea how to do it?
I'm sure it's pretty easy but I wasn't able to find anything ...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`NSNumber` is an object type. Unlike `NSString`, the actual value of *NSNumber* is not substitued when used with `%@` format. You have to get the actual value using the predefined methods, like `intValue` which returns the integer value. And use the format substituer as `%d` as we are going to substitute an integer value.

The predicate should be,

```
predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %d", [stdUserNumber intValue]];
```

Comment: Great thank you so much! Is there a list of all these %d %i %@ %... "shortcuts"?

Comment: ... this shouldn't make a difference.  The predicate format parser will see the `%d` in the format string, pop an `int` off the `va_list`, and then box it in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: That's strange because I also tried:
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userID == %i", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"standardUser"]]];
And that didn't work ... so it has to be the %d !? ... Anyways, it's working now :)

Comment: This saved me some time for sure. Since I was writing most of the code in swift and only used %@ for defining the predicate, it totally slipped off my mind that we need to use correct format substitutes.

Comment: Here's a list of all format specifiers: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using predicateWithSubstitutionVariables: and value you want to predicate is NSNumber with integer value then you need to use NSNumber in predicate instead of NSString as substitution value. Take a look at example:

```
NSPredicate *genrePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"genreID == $GENRE_ID"]]; //if we make only one NSPredicate if would look something like this: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"genreID == %d", [someString integerValue]];

NSPredicate *localPredicate = nil;
for(NSDictionary *genre in genresArray){
    localPredicate = [genrePredicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"GENRE_ID" : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[genre[@"genre_id"] integerValue]]}];
}
```